# OOM error after variable initialization in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

This is my error:

```
OOM when allocating tensor of shape [7,7,512,4096] and type float
 [[Node: W6/Adam/Initializer/zeros = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [7,7,512,4096] values: [[[0 0 0]]]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

In the traceback I can see that it's caused by this line:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

All parameters combined use around 1,5Gb of memory. I have 4 Gb of memory available.

I have already tried without success:

```
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.40
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT:

How did I calculate the amount of used memory?

```
    var_sizes = [np.product(list(map(int, v.shape))) * v.dtype.size
         for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)]
    print(sum(var_sizes) / (1024 ** 2), 'MB')
```

Comment: My guess is that you actually need more than 1.5Gb. How did you obtain this number?

Comment: I added the information. Shouldn't be an issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your calculation, you compute the amount of memory necessary to hold your variables. However this is only a fraction of the memory you need. You are missing in particular:

- The neuron outputs (i.e. the features).
- The gradient of your cost function with respect to your model parameters and the features.

Tensorflow does try to optimize memory when possible, but that gives you a ballpark estimate. So I would not be surprised if you need more than 4Gb in total after all.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Do you know a way to compute the required amount of memory upfront? Can I make tensorflow store some intermediate results in RAM and use it again later?

Comment: To estimate the memory footprint ahead of the computation, I would do a manual ballpark estimate calculation based on those elements (parameters, outputs, and their gradients, maybe also counting constants if they are significant --hopefully not). Reducing your batch size can sometimes be an easy solution if you do not care to change your net.

Comment: Okay so I can double my estimated number by also taking the gradients into account. Regarding feature maps, I thought they will be deleted as soon as they are not needed anymore. So 1.5GB*2 = 3GB + 1GB for an intermediate feature map should be sufficient.

Comment: @siva Be careful, feature maps are usually needed to compute gradients. They are kept until gradients are back-propagated downstream.